# Change one value of an object within a Map

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's assume I have a map data type

```
testMap: Map<string, any>
```

The string value is my key and any is always an object within that Map.

The object could look like this:

```
{ name: 'testName', age: 20}
```

Let's assume that the user selects an element with a key via a dropdown.

How can I now change the name of an object to the corresponding key via this key?

I already iterated over the map with forEach and tried to change a property with Map.get() and Map.set(). Unfortunately this did not work.

Comment: copy to a new key with updated info, remove the original

Comment: Please show the code you tried as a [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somthing like this?

```js
// Assuming you have the testMap already defined
// testMap: Map<string, any>

// Step 1: Get the selected key from the dropdown (replace 'selectedKey' with the actual selected key)
const selectedKey = 'someKey';

// Step 2: Retrieve the corresponding object from the map
const selectedObject = testMap.get(selectedKey);

// Step 3: Update the "name" property of the object
if (selectedObject) {
  selectedObject.name = selectedKey;
} else {
  // Handle the case when the selected key is not found in the map
  console.error('Selected key not found in the map!');
}

// Step 4: Set the updated object back into the map using the same key
testMap.set(selectedKey, selectedObject);

// Now, the "name" property of the selected object in the map should be updated to the selected key.
```

Comment: `testMap.set(selectedKey, selectedObject);` is not at all necessary.